# Does the thread supported by the kernel run in the kernel state?

Tags: java, linux, operating-system, pthreads

I'm a little confused about kernel space, userspace, kernel thread, user thread. Whether you can think that kernel threads are supported by the kernel is running in kernel space?

Java,

```
`Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable...)`,
```

This thread named 't' is called a lightweight process (kernel thread) in Linux. Is it running in the kernel state?

Comment: No. It is part of the user process running the JVM. The thread named `t` is a Java object, and it is *associated* with a user-space thread created by the kernel. `t` itself is not a lightweight process in Linux, and a lightweight process is not a kernel thread.

Comment: Thank you,  can I think that: lightweight process is a kernel-level thread that runs in user space.  And I see the Linux documentation saying that Linux uses a lightweight process to implement the posix standard thread.  So I said `t` is a lightweight process  in Linux.  I mean ‘lightweight process (kernel thread)’ means that the lightweight process is scheduled by the kernel, so it is a kernel-level thread.

Answer (score 1):

Need some fundamental OS concepts clarification:

- Kernel thread is a thread entity that is managed and scheduled by OS kernel directly. User level program can access kernel thread through system calls such as via pthread APIs. If a user program binds its code execution with a kernel thread, it is then a user thread that is mapped to a kernel thread.
- Light-weight process is not a well-defined term, but it usually refers to a kernel thread that is exposed to user space, in contrast to normal process which is heavier than a thread. In this sense, you can consider kernel thread is the same as light-weight process.
- Java thread is a user thread entity that is normally supported by a kernel thread (or you can call it a light-weight process). That means, the execution of a Java thread can be scheduled directly by the OS kernel.

So you are correct that a Java thread is mapped to a kernel thread, but Java thread does not run in kernel space. It is scheduled by the OS kernel directly, and surely has kernel thread data in kernel space. And sometimes a user thread may run in kernel space, when it invokes system call...

Comment: Thank you very straightforward to explain, let me clear up a lot of concepts. I feel that I need to strengthen my knowledge of user thread mapping kernel thread.